# The number of divisors of the form $(2n+1)(n-integer)$ for the integer 1024

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My idea was to factorize 1024 and then pick factors which was of the given form but it is a herculean job. Is there any elegant algorithm for doing these type of questions ?

Thank You.

Comment: 1024 is a power of 2.  The only odd factor is 1.

Comment: @ElizabethS.Q.Goodman Still, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @HGSur: What are you missing? Elizabeth just handed you a full, complete solution.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm sorry. I don't know what theorem to use.

Comment: @HGSur: You don't need a theorem. You just need to count how many elements the set $\{1\}$ has. Namely: One!

Comment: I'm completely new to this type of questions -- can you provide a link to any resources related to this ?

Comment: H G Sur: if $n$ is an integer, then $2n+1$ is odd.  Is this exactly how the problem is written?  There may be some missing context.

Comment: So the answer 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the conversation above, I will try my best to clarify the whole matter.

Ok, so the question is : How many factors of the form $2n+1$, where $n$ is an integer, does the number $1024$ have?

I shall go point by point.  At any stage, if you do not understand, please intimate me in the comments below.

1) For any integer $n$, the integer $2n+1$, is *odd*.  Can you see why?

2) When you break $1024$ into prime factors, you get $1024 = 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2$, which we write in short as $2^{10}$.

Note : *For the moment, you can assume this is a Herculean job. However, in fifth standard, I used to factorize numbers like $17711$ for fun , so I suppose this is a piece of cake for me, and 'twould be nice if you make it so in your case too. *.

3) From the above, can you tell me exactly what numbers are the factors of $1024$? If you don't know, hover over this yellow box :

> By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, let $l$ be a divisor of $1024$. Then,note that if a prime $p$ divides $l$, then that prime also divides $1024$, since $l$ divides $1024$. However, the only *prime* dividing $1024$ (look at the factorization) is $2$. Hence, we see that the only prime dividing $l$ is $2$, so $l = 2\times 2 \times ... \times 2$ some number of times. But because $l \leq 1024$, we have that $l$ can be any one of : $1,2,2 \times 2,2\times 2\times 2,2\times 2\times 2\times 2,2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2,2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2,2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2,2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2,2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2,2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2 $ (the last one is just $1024$).

4) How many of the factors you have written above, are *odd*? (Hint: A number is odd if and only if it is not divisible by $2$). Again, look at the hidden answer below for more details:

> The only odd number is $1$, since all other numbers are divisible by $2$ (they contain at least one two in their prime factorization).

5) Having done all the above, can you find the answer? Again, a hint below:

> There's only one odd factor, $1$. $1$ is of the form $2n+1$, where $n=0$, which is an integer. Hence, there is precisely **one** factor of the form $2n+1$, which is $1$.

Once again: I could not estimate your level from the above conversation, so please feel free to bother me over this answer.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I get all the points mentioned in your answer. I've only one difficulty though : What about the $(n-integer)$ part ? In this case we have n=0, then $(2n+1)(n-integer)=0\implies1(0-integer) $?

Comment: It seems like you have written $2n+1 = 0$. That is incorrect. See, we want *factors of the type* $2n+1$. I am saying that the number $1$, is of the type *2n+1*, since $1 = 2*0 + 1$,  where $0$ is an integer (we want $n$ to be an integer, right?). Hence, there is exactly **one** factor of the type $2n+1$.  So, with $n=0$, we have the factor $2n+1 = 1$. *For all other $n$, $2n+1$ is not a factor of $1024$*.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now :)

Comment: Great. You are welcome.